# Drawing a triangle a star relative to a given point

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to make some questions for my students. They have to find the next drawing. But therefore I have to make different grids following one after each other. The best result I could come was this:

```
  \documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
   \usepackage{tikz,tkz-base, pgf, tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc,intersections, decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\tkzInit[ymin=0,ymax=7,xmin=0,xmax=7]
\tkzClip
\tkzGrid
\node at (2.5,1.5) {$\Delta$};
\filldraw (3,4) rectangle (4,5);
\filldraw (3.5,3.5) circle (0.4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The problem is the changing the scale would make the $\Delta$ becoming greater then the box it's in. It would also be nice to have other shapes or jpeg in the grids to would go with the scale (stars, smiley's, ...)
The point is always the center of a square of the grid.

[image]

Comment: Nodes do not scale with a scope’s transformation. Though you can add `transform shape` to their options. (There is not really a question. ;))

Comment: Well the question is ... can I make this example better, with different shapes (jpegs, triangles,... ;))

Comment: I'm not really clear about what you want to do.  Is this a scaling issue?  Is this a placement issue?  Your title suggests one thing; your question seems to suggest something else.  If you were going to be drawing such things by hand, what exactly would be you be doing?  (I'm not actually suggesting you do it by hand.  But maybe if you can explain at that level, we'll better know what you want.)

Comment: @A.Ellett The problem is that I want to make 3 grids with shapes. First grid (example) two rectangles, one triangle,... Second grid three rectangles, two triangles, third grid four rectangles, three triangles. (variations of this are endless) Therefore I needed to have a easy and a quick way to place this shapes in the grids. As I (sometimes) have to scale the grids, characters is not the way to go.  \filldraw (2.1,1.1) -- + (0.8cm,0cm) -- + (0.4cm,0.8cm) -- cycle;
already gave me the triangle. Jpegs would be nice (it's for kids of 12 year)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a big fan of scaling in TikZ (or even changing the value of the dimensions of coordinates via `x` or `y`).  Invariably, when I take such approaches, I run into trouble because I perform some kind of transformation of coordinates in which such rescaling appears to be ignored.  This is not to say that scaling and such are bad; I suppose, if I had a proper understanding of how canvas transformations worked in TikZ, I might not be so averse to these techniques.

So, I take one of two other approaches.  Either I define my own *scaling unit* and thus have precise control over when and where it will take effect (some will say that I'm overcompensating due to my *fear* of scaling), or I create a `standalone` document which I can scale via the `graphicx` package.  These two approach also have their drawbacks:  generally I go with the first approach.

The first approach is probably not what you want, because it will not scale *characters/graphics* that you import into the document.  Nevertheless, here's an example of what I mean:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%% for Circle and Square the placement of the object is 
%% relative to the South West corner                    
\def\aeplaceCircle(#1,#2);{ \draw[fill] (#1,#2) ++ (0.5\aes,0.5\aes) circle (0.4\aes);  }
\def\aeplaceSquare(#1,#2);{ \draw[fill] (#1,#2) rectangle ++(1\aes,1\aes);}
\def\aeplaceChar(#1,#2)#3;{ \path (#1,#2) ++ (0.5\aes,0.5\aes) node {#3}; }
\begin{document}

Here's my grid:

\def\aes{in*0.25}%% my scaling unit!
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[step=1\aes] (0,0) grid (5\aes,5\aes);

  \aeplaceCircle(2\aes,2\aes);
  \aeplaceSquare(3\aes,4\aes);
  \aeplaceChar(4\aes,2\aes){$\triangle$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

resulting in

[image]

For the second approach, here's the `standalone` document which I call `example_02.tex`.

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%% for Circle and Square the placement of the object is 
%% relative to the South West corner                    
\def\aeplaceCircle(#1,#2);{ \draw[fill] (#1,#2) ++ (0.5,0.5) circle (0.4);  }
\def\aeplaceSquare(#1,#2);{ \draw[fill] (#1,#2) rectangle ++(1,1);}
\def\aeplaceChar(#1,#2)#3;{ \path (#1,#2) ++ (0.5,0.5) node[yshift=-3pt] {\scalebox{2.5}{#3}}; }
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[step=1] (0,0) grid (5,5);

  \aeplaceCircle(2,2);
  \aeplaceSquare(3,4);
  \aeplaceChar(4,2){$\triangle$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Before I can use this in my main document, I'll have to compile it on its own.  Then,
I import this `standalone` document into my main document as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

Here's a very large grid:

\includegraphics[scale=2]{example_02}

Here's a moderately sized grid 

\includegraphics[height=3in]{example_02}

Here's the grid at its natural size:

\includegraphics{example_02}


\end{document}
```

which results in

[image]

**There are various draw backs to these two approaches.**

In the first approach, I need to write `\aes` everywhere I want the scaling.  And, frankly, most people would probably not put up with that sort of nonsense.  Nevertheless, it's an approach I frequently take myself due to the nature of the documents I create for my students.

The second approach has possibly two drawbacks.  The first, which is rather minimal, is that you must compile two separate documents.  Though, depending on contingencies between the graphic and the document, this can become unwieldy---I create a lot of documents where the graphic is extremely context sensitive and needs to be created simultaneously 
in context.  Though many on this site will see no problem with this approach.  However, the second drawback will be that, after scaling via `\includegraphics`, any text in the imported image will not match the text in the main document (this is *in fact* where TikZ scaling mechanism is very nice because it generally takes into account the difference between text and graphics when scaling).  If there is no such text to worry about, then this isn't really a concern.  And, from your description of what you're doing, it would seem this is the approach for you.

**Simplifying drawing the objects**

One thing you should note is that, if your objects are relatively consistent, I would define macros for handling their placement.  That way you can avoid unwieldy code (which can be hard to read and debug later) in favor of code that readily identifies what you're doing.  Hence the creation of the macros:

```
%% for Circle and Square the placement of the object is 
%% relative to the South West corner                    
\def\aeplaceCircle(#1,#2);{ \draw[fill] (#1,#2) ++ (0.5,0.5) circle (0.4);  }
\def\aeplaceSquare(#1,#2);{ \draw[fill] (#1,#2) rectangle ++(1,1);}
\def\aeplaceChar(#1,#2)#3;{ \path (#1,#2) ++ (0.5,0.5) node[yshift=-3pt] {\scalebox{2.5}{#3}}; }
```

I use `\def` here because it allows me to write the macros using a syntax similar to that used in TikZ.
And this gives you a quick way to place the objects where you want as in

```
\aeplaceSquare(3,4);
```

Comment: Scaling via `\includegraphics` also scales the line-width, doesn't it?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel most definitely which TikZ scaling very nicely also avoids

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel but i'm thinking that in this context that perhaps doesn't matter so much.

Comment: I use scaling a lot because i thought it was the best way for me to make things fit on the paper I needed. Sometimes it is for an A4 format, but sometimes the same picture I need for a beamer format.